# Devise - Sign in On Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

I am using devise gem in a rails application with multiple subdomains and multiple schema.

Each subdomain is handled by controller, which look like this on `application_controller.rb` :

```
def load_subdomain
    @account = Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #admin login in domain
    if resource.is_a?(admin) 
      admin_path
    #user login in subdomain
    elsif resource.is_a?(user)
      subdomain_root_path
    else
      super
    end    
  end
```

on routes.rb

```
    match '/' => 'subdomains#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }, :as => :subdomain_root

devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login/user' => 'sesusers#new', :as => :new_session_user
    post '/signin/user' => 'sesusers#create', :as => :user_session
    delete '/logout/user' => 'sesusers#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    post '/send/user' => 'passwordusers#create', :as => :passwordusers_create
    get '/change_password/user' => 'passwordusers#edit', :as => :passwordusers_edit
    put '/change/user' =>  'passwordusers#update', :as => :passwordusers_update
  end
```

This leads to having multiple sign_in urls for each sub-domains.

```
subdomain1.lvh.me:3000/login/user
subdomain2.lvh.me:3000/login/user
subdomain3.lvh.me:3000/login/user
...
...
etc
```

on sesusers_controller.rb

```
class SesusersController < Devise::SessionsController
  include Tenantable::Schema::Controller
  before_filter :load_subdomain

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    logger.info "Logged in"
    super
  end

  def destroy
    logger.info "Logout success"
    super
  end
end
```

When I try login, success login and redirect to subdomain_root_path

```
Started POST "/signin/user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-08 20:36:04 +0700
Processing by SesusersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"DJ/MJnHU5pHwxQQYDSvwyBsawmx
/9Ms7CXx3me0MBBE=", "user"=>{"email"=>"demouser@domain.com", "password"=>"
[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  Account Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WH
ERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain" = 'subdomain1' LIMIT 1
Logged in
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'demouser@domain.com' LIMIT 1
   (2.0ms)  BEGIN
   (53.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-04-08 12:55:28.631212'
, "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-04-08 13:36:04.615889', "sign_in_count" = 4 WHERE
 "users"."id" = 16
   (7.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://subdomain1.lvh.me:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1589ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-08 20:36:06 +0700
Processing by SubdomainsController#index as HTML
  Account Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WH
ERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain" = 'subdomain1' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "pu
blic"."accounts"."subdomain" = 'subdomain1' LIMIT 1
   (30.0ms)  select sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name
)) from information_schema.tables where table_schema in ('subdomain') group by tab
le_schema
  Rendered subdomains/index.html.erb within layouts/subdomain (81.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 170ms (Views: 130.0ms | ActiveRecord: 33.0ms)
```

look, successful login.. view subdomain

```
<div class="pull-right">
     <div class="btn-group">
         <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to current_user.name, '#', { :class => 'btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' } %>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li> <%= link_to "Dashboard", '#', 'style' =>"color:#fff" %></li>
                </ul>
         <% else %>
            <%= link_to ('<i class="icon-lock icon-white"></i>').html_safe + " Login" +(' <span class="caret"></span>').html_safe , '#', { :class => 'btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown' } %>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><%= link_to "User", new_session_user_path, 'style' =>"color:#000" %></li>

                </ul>
         <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

But on view subdomain `current_user.name` not display, appears only login button.

can someone help me?

thanks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to share the user session between the subdomain for this, so that one session can be continued with multiple subdomains.

You should modify the `session_store.rb` file in initializes as,

```
  DemoApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_jcrop_app_session', domain: ".maindomain.com"
```

Adding the domain will work and careful with the last leading "**.**" (period) which is needed for sub domain.

Comment: oopss, I was wrong configuration such as `*.lvh.me`.. thanks bro.

Comment: The like is actually: `DemoApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_jcrop_app_session', domain: ".maindomain.com" `